# ¿que esta pasando?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, pdo

Estoy haciendo un CRUD y al terminar de llenar el formulario aparece que el "paciente se ha registrado", eso es lo que debería decir si se envían correctamente los registros a la tabla. PERO al ir a la tabla no hay nada (no aparecen los registros) el código no parece tener errores de sintaxis según el procesador de texto. pueden ayudarme?

los códigos son los siguientes:

/*conexion*/

```
<?php

try {

    $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bdnutriologo','root','');

    $base->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");

}catch(Exception $e){

    die ('error' .$e->getMessage());
    echo "linea del error" .$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

/*inserción de registros a la base de datos mediante PDO*/

```
<?php

include ("conexion.php");

 $registros=$base->query("SELECT * FROM expediente")- 
 >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

 if(isset($_POST["cr"])){

 $id_exp=$_POST["id_exp"];

 $peso=$_POST["peso"];

 $edad=$_POST["edad"];

 $estatura=$_POST["estatura"];

 $fecha_registro=$_POST["fecha_registro"];

$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];

$objetivo=$_POST["objetivo"];

$sql="INSERT INTO expediente (id_exp, peso, edad, estatura, fecha_registro, sexo, objetivo ) VALUES (:idx, :pes, :edd, :est, :fech, :sex, :obj)";


$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);

$resultado->execute(array(":idx"=>$id_exp, ":pes"=>$peso, ":edd"=>$edad, ":est"=>$estatura, ":fech"=>$fecha_registro, ":sex"=>$sexo, ":obj"=>$objeto)); 

}

echo "El paciente fue dado de alta.";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que varias cosas deben tenerse en cuenta para optimizar tu código:

- Evaluar de forma correcta lo que ocurre en cada momento, escribiendo un código controlado
- Hacer un manejo de errores lo más específico posible. En el caso de PDO, se pueden obtener errores relativos al objeto `PDO` en sí, o al objeto `PDOStatement`. Creo que aquí conviene usar éste último, para ser más específicos.
- Puedes valerte también de `rowCount()` para mostrar la cantidad de filas que fueron insertadas.

Propondría esta solución:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO expediente (id_exp, peso, edad, estatura, fecha_registro, sexo, objetivo ) VALUES (:idx, :pes, :edd, :est, :fech, :sex, :obj)";

$stmt=$base->prepare($sql);
$arrParams=array(":idx"=>$id_exp, ":pes"=>$peso, ":edd"=>$edad, ":est"=>$estatura, ":fech"=>$fecha_registro, ":sex"=>$sexo, ":obj"=>$objeto);
$resultado=$stmt->execute($arrParams); 

$msgInfo=($resultado) ? "Se insertaron ".$stmt->rowCount(). " registros" : "¡Error! ".$stmt->errorInfo()[2];
echo $msgInfo;
```

La clave aquí es la línea donde se crea la variable `$msgInfo`. En ella se evalúa el valor de `$resultado` mediante un operador ternario. Si es verdadero, significa que la consulta ocurrió con éxito, en ese caso `$msgInfo` será un mensaje al respecto, indicando la cantidad de filas que se insertaron. De lo contrario, `$msgInfo` adquirirá el valor de un mensaje de error, obtenido de `$stmt->errorInfo()[2]`. El valor `2` que aparece ahí es porque `errorInfo` devuelve un array, y el mensaje de error se encuentra en la clave `2` de ese array.

---

#### Optimizar la cadena de conexión

Viendo la forma en que te conectas, te comento que puedes optimizar tu conexión de este modo:

```
    $arrOptions = array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    );

    $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=bdnutriologo','root',$arrOptions);
```

Como podrás apreciar, he creado una variable `$arrOptions` en la cual indico **cómo quiero de mi conexión** y paso ese array como último parámetro de mi conexión. Eso evitará **aplicar dos métodos al objeto después de haberlo creado**.

Entre las opciones he puesto una que es muy importante para la seguridad: `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE`, no ponerla podría suponer que PDO podría emular las consultas preparadas y en algunos escenarios te podrían colar una Inyección SQL.

Answer (score 3):

El mensaje de dado de alta te sale porque es independiente del resultado de la inserción.

El método [execute](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php) devuelve un True or False dependiendo del éxito de la query ¿Por qué no intentas controlarlo con eso?

Edito: El método específico para errores con PDO es [ErrorInfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php), en la página de ejemplo sale tal que así.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('bogus sql');

if (!$stmt) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}
```

Donde *$stmt* sería tu *$resultado*.